# How do I recover a Berkeley DB (included in a Sun Grid Engine installation)?

Tags: gridengine, berkeleydb

I'm on CentOS 5.

```
[root@newjanux spooldb]# uname -a
Linux newjanux 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:28:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and SGE 6.2u2

I already have copies of the original database just in case ... berkeley db won't start for corruption. The tool which supposedly fixes this comes with the package but it fails (in the same way):

```
[root@newjanux spooldb]# /opt/sge/utilbin/lx24-amd64/db_recover -v -c 
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 2136 offset 2719640
db_recover: Log file corrupt at LSN: [399][10485626]
db_recover: PANIC: Invalid argument
db_recover: DB_ENV->open: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
```

Well, I thought I *was* running the database recovery!

Now what?

Comment: What happens when you try without `-c`?

Comment: good question; answer is "same thing."

[root@newjanux spooldb]# /opt/sge/utilbin/lx24-amd64/db_recover -v 
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 2136 offset 2719640
db_recover: Log file corrupt at LSN: [399][10485626]
db_recover: PANIC: Invalid argument
db_recover: DB_ENV->open: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery

Comment: At this point I'd rather just have the dateabase with the queues established. there are no jobs running so no data to preserve.

Comment: I seem to have wound the errors down to this:

07/10/2013 15:50:56|  main|sol|E|couldn't open berkeley database "sge": (13) Permission denied
07/10/2013 15:50:56|  main|sol|E|startup of rule "default rule" in context "berkeleydb spooling" failed
07/10/2013 15:50:56|  main|sol|C|setup failed

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `-c` option, you have to restore a clean copy of the database, along with all of the logs generated after that backup copy was made. The `-c` option then uses the logs to apply the missing transactions.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/programmer_reference/transapp_recovery.html